# Destroying widgets from a different subroutine in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, destroy

So I'm using .place to set the location of my widgets at the moment.

```
def printresults():
    SClabelspare=Label(cwindow, text ="Please enter the Customers ID Number:" ).place(x=10,y=560)
```

I'm looking to call another subroutine that will destroy these widgets. I believe there is something called .destroy() or .place_destroy? I'm not quite sure how these would work though and I have tried to create one that looked like this:

```
def destroy_widgets():
    SClabelspare.destroy()
```

but it just produces an error code that says `NameError: global name 'SClabelspare' is not defined`

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Don't apologize for the formatting, fix the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

First, place() returns None so SClabelspare==None not a Tkinter ID.  Second it is local, so is garbage collected when the function exits.  You have to keep a reference to the object which can be done in many ways.  A Python tutorial would be a good idea to get the basics before you go further https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers  Also, programming a Tkinter app without using class structures is a frustrating experience, unless it is something very simple.  Otherwise you get errors like yours and have to spend much time and effort trying to overcome them. This is an example that I already have and is meant to to give a general idea of the process.

```
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial

class ButtonsTest:
   def __init__(self):
      self.top = Tk()
      self.top.title("Click a button to remove")
      Label(self.top, text="Click a button to remove it",
            bg="lightyellow").grid(row=0)

      self.top_frame = Frame(self.top, width =400, height=400)
      self.button_dic = {}
      self.buttons()
      self.top_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

      Button(self.top_frame, text='Exit', bg="orange",
             command=self.top.quit).grid(row=10,column=0, columnspan=5)

      self.top.mainloop()

   ##-------------------------------------------------------------------         
   def buttons(self):
      b_row=1
      b_col=0
      for but_num in range(1, 11):
         ## create a button and send the button's number to
         ## self.cb_handler when the button is pressed
         b = Button(self.top_frame, text = str(but_num), 
                    command=partial(self.cb_handler, but_num))
         b.grid(row=b_row, column=b_col)
         ## dictionary key=button number --> button instance
         self.button_dic[but_num] = b

         b_col += 1
         if b_col > 4:
            b_col = 0
            b_row += 1

   ##----------------------------------------------------------------
   def cb_handler( self, cb_number ):
      print "\ncb_handler", cb_number
      self.button_dic[cb_number].grid_forget()

##===================================================================
BT=ButtonsTest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if this is *supposed* to be very simple, without a lot of hard-to-manage global variables, and if class structures would only introduce needless complexity, you might try something like this (it worked for me in the python3 interpreter from the command line):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def victim():
    global vic
    vic = Toplevel(root)
    vicblab = Label(vic, text='Please bump me off')
    vicblab.grid()

def bumper():
    global vic
    bump = Toplevel(root)
    bumpbutt = Button(bump, text='Bump off', command=vic.destroy)
    bumpbutt.grid()

victim()
bumper()
```